# How to check undefined resource attribute within CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to check undefined resource attribute (returned by Fn::GetAtt) within CloudFormation template?

I would like to include specified resource's attributes in the stack's outputs using Fn::GetAtt only if those attributes are defined.

For example, creating stack using the following template gives me an error:

"*Attribute: StreamArn was not found for resource: MyTestStack-DDBTable-1C0T2MJZA1J0I. Rollback requested by user.*"

because the stream specification is not included in the resource properties of this specific table.

Of course, the simple way to fix this is just to remove StreamArn from the stack outputs list. However, I still would like to know how to check whether the attribute is defined for specified resource or not.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

- Pat

```html
{
   "Resources":{
      "DDBTable":{
         "Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
         "Properties":{
            "AttributeDefinitions":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"ArtistId",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Concert",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"TicketSales",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               }
            ],
            "GlobalSecondaryIndexes":[
               {
                  "IndexName":"GSI",
                  "KeySchema":[
                     {
                        "AttributeName":"TicketSales",
                        "KeyType":"HASH"
                     }
                  ],
                  "Projection":{
                     "ProjectionType":"KEYS_ONLY"
                  },
                  "ProvisionedThroughput":{
                     "ReadCapacityUnits":5,
                     "WriteCapacityUnits":5
                  }
               }
            ],
            "KeySchema":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"ArtistId",
                  "KeyType":"HASH"
               },
               {
                  "AttributeName":"Concert",
                  "KeyType":"RANGE"
               }
            ],
            "ProvisionedThroughput":{
               "ReadCapacityUnits":5,
               "WriteCapacityUnits":5
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "DDBTablePhysicalID":{
         "Value":{
            "Ref":"DDBTable"
         }
      },
      "DDBTableArn":{
         "Value":{
            "Fn::GetAtt":[
               "DDBTable",
               "Arn"
            ]
         }
      },
      "DDBTableStreamArn":{
         "Value":{
            "Fn::GetAtt":[
               "DDBTable",
               "StreamArn"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only if those attributes are defined.

Its **not supported** in plain CFN. You have to do it by defining your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in the form of a lambda fuction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Anyway, is there a way to only ignore Fn::GetAtt failure to prevent stack rollback and still enable stack rollback for all other types of failure?